# What type of database to store this data structure with lists

Tags: database, postgresql, data-structures

I have a data-structure which consists of key:value pairs were the keys are integers and the values are itself lists with a condition on it. The condition is the elements in each list should all be positive and sum to 1. At the moment I am not interested in relations between the keys. Say I have `4` then I am not interested in the next key `12`.

Example (written as a Python dictionary):

```
{ 4: [0.34, 0.66],
 12: [0.1, 0.9],
 34: [0.25, 0.25, 0.5],
 98: [1.0]}
```

My question is what kind of database system would be best to store this and how? I prefer to store it in a PostgreSQL database, however if another db architecture or philosophy would be a better fit then I am open for that.

Currently I store it in a PostgreSQL db where the lists are fit into a single field for each record. However this is imo an ugly solution, I do not think db fields should contain lists. If the condition for the lists wouldn't be necassary then I would just store each element for the lists together with the corresponding key in a single record, like this:

```
[( 4, 0.34),
 ( 4, 0.66),
 (12, 0.1),
 (12, 0.9),
 (34, 0.25),
 (34, 0.25),
 (34, 0.5),
 (98, 1.0)]
```

However the condition is important and should not break. Therefore I think this is not a good solution as records are independent of each other. So what would be a good solution?

Comment: Do you process the elements of these lists inside the database, e.g. have them appear in `WHERE` clauses? If not or not much, use a PostgreSQL array and you should be fine.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe No processing is done by a Python script. Database is only used for storage. If you say arrays are fine then I might keep them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you treat the lists as a single element in the database, using an array in PostgreSQL would be a good solution.

Arrays become problematic if you use single elements in database processing, e.g. use an array element in a `WHERE` condition or want to base referential constraints on array elements.

In a way, if the list is a single thing as far as the database is concerned, I would argue that it does not really violate the first normal form if you use an array to store it.